# javascript change background on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this progress bar working. The only thing I am having issues with is changing the color when as many of the check boxes are checked...

```
0-3 background = red
4-7 = yellow
8-10 = Green
```

My CSS

```
.progress-bar-wrapper .progress-bar-filling {
height: 100%;
color: #fff;
text-align: right;
width: 0;
background-color: #39b54a;
border-radius:20px;
}

.progress-bar-wrapper .progress-bar-percent {
font-weight: 400;
font-family: sans-serif;
color: #626162;
padding-top: 6px;
display: block;
}
```

My HTML / Javascript

```
<div id="yyy">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<div>
<script>

window.onload = xxx;


function xxx()
{
var zzz = $(".check_id:checked").length;
document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = zzz


$(document).ready(function(){
function progress(percent, $element) {
var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
$element.find('.progress-bar-filling').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 300)
```

The jFiddle is here [Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLq07L77/)
Thanks

Comment: You don't need an onload if you're using document.ready, it's best to put all your code inside the document.ready

Comment: Ahh other answers beat me to the punch, so I won't post an answer, but here's a working Fiddle based on yours if you want it :) https://jsfiddle.net/zhLe0fk9/1/

Comment: you don't need document.ready() inside function xxx() as this function is called onload() and  onclick()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check the no. of checked checkboxes via `$(".check_id:checked").length` and change just the `background-color css` property.

```
<div id="yyy">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<div>
<script>

window.onload = xxx;


function xxx()
{
  var zzz = $(".check_id:checked").length;
  document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = zzz


    $(document).ready(function(){
    function progress(percent, $element) {
      var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
      $element.find('.progress-bar-filling').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 300)
      //.html(percent + "%&nbsp;");

      $('.progress-bar-percent').html( percent + "%&nbsp;" );

      // calculate color
      if($(".check_id:checked").length <= 3)
      {
         $("#progress-bar-filling").css("background-color","red");
      }
      else if($(".check_id:checked").length >= 4 && $(".check_id:checked").length <= 7 )
      {
          $("#progress-bar-filling").css("background-color","yellow");
      }      
      else if($(".check_id:checked").length >= 8 &&    $(".check_id:checked").length <= 10 )
      {
          $("#progress-bar-filling").css("background-color","green");
      }
  }

  var complete = zzz+'0';
  progress(complete, $('#progress-bar'));
})
}




</script>
<p id="insert"></p>

<div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
  <div id="progress-bar">
    <div id="progress-bar-filling" class="progress-bar-filling"></div>
  </div>
     <div class="progress-bar-percent"></div>
 </div>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/tLq07L77/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the number of `:checked` checkboxers you can add 3 new classes (in your css) to set the background-color of your progress-bar:

```
.progress-bar-wrapper .progress-bar-filling.fill0 {
  background-color: red;
}
.progress-bar-wrapper .progress-bar-filling.fill1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.progress-bar-wrapper .progress-bar-filling.fill2 {
  background-color: #39b54a;
}
```

Inside your `javascript` code - first - remove all the `fill0,fill1,fill2` classes, and then - based on the number you have - add only the relevant class:

```
$('.progress-bar-filling').removeClass('fill0 fill1 fill2');
if (zzz <= 3) {
  $('.progress-bar-filling').addClass('fill0')
} else if (zzz <= 7) {
  $('.progress-bar-filling').addClass('fill1')
} else {
  $('.progress-bar-filling').addClass('fill2')
}
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/g4Lhvawq/